# Why is foundObj._id showing undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
deleteCrypto(name){
      let foundObj = this.Cryptos.find(x => x.name === name);

      let indexOfArrayItem = this.Cryptos.findIndex(i => i._id === foundObj._id);

      axios.delete(`${this.baseApiURL}/delete-crypto/${foundObj._id}`).then(() => {
        this.Cryptos.splice(indexOfArrayItem, 1);

        this.getCryptos()
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

foundObj._id should evaluate to an _id field for a mongodb document but it evaluates to undefined.

Comment: If an object field is undefined when you don't expect it to be, the first thing you should do is log out the full value of the object to see if _it_ is what you expect. What does that get you?

Comment: @NathanWiles the object itself evaluates to undefined

Comment: There's your answer, then. `Cryptos` has no entry for which `name` matches the `name` value passed in.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Please also describe your problem _before_ showing code.